# How do I use the live video stream from my arduino camera (connected by serial), to run with my OpenCV python ball tracking code?

Tags: arduino, opencv

My objective is to have the arduino camera, just to act like a webcam, and have my laptop run a ball tracking script on it. The ball tracking script already works with my laptops camera, and it can also do the ball tracking overlay on a video file (.mp4).

I am using an Arduino Uno with an Arducam Mini 2MP plus. Using the Arduino IDE and ArduCAM's host software, I am getting about 4-6 fps (which I am fine with). Frame rate isn't too important to me, I just want the arduino camera to act in the place of my laptop's webcam.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.